# Using Apache HBase on a single server

Tags: apache, hbase

I'm new to NoSQL DBs and Apache HBase but I want to learn it.
And I was wondering if I can use HBase with just one server because what I know so far is that there are 3 modes with which HBase can run.
1. Standalone
2. Pseudo-distributed
3. Fully-distributed

so on a single server I'm only able to use standalone and pseudo-distributed but here's the problem, because I've found that these 2 modes are not supposed to be used in production environment.

The question is: Can I use Fully-distributed configuration with a single server or am I forced to buy more servers in order to run HBase in Fully-distributed production environment?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pseudo-distributed configuration is just a fully-distributed running on a single host. You can find a detailed explanation  here: http://hbase.apache.org/book/standalone_dist.html

It's up to you to run it in production but It's totally discouraged, if your scale is so small perhaps you should consider simpler options that suit your needs (our good old friends RDBMS maybe?)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have one more question. If I will use MySQL and if we consider that there will be for example 500 people online on instant chat, where every user will send a message for example every 5 seconds, will MySQL handle that amount of data? (Message will be delivered through Node.js, MySQL will be used for chat history) PS. I know that it is not much users compared with other websites but I'm running this on VPS with 2 GB of RAM and 2 GHz processor.

Comment: @peterpetr4 Even when not optimal for that purpose you can even make it work with mysql by working on memory at your backend and persisting batches to mysql every minute + some daily pruning to remove old messages. There are almost infinite implementations and a lot of different technologies, you can find many opensource nodejs apps already doing that with redis/mongodb/couchbase: https://github.com/NKjoep/Nodejs-Persistent-Chat http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/building-chat-application-using-nodejs.html  http://thelimbeck.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/simple-chatrooms-with-redis/ ...